# Google Places API returns non-included types

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am using the Google Places API and don't seem to understand why the API is including results that don't include my requested type.  I am looking for convenience stores in an area and built the query below.

Putting it another way, if I look at the types associated with my placeIDs using the place details API for each of my results, I can't find "convenience_store" in the listed types for each placeID, except for one location.

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=49,-122.2&radius=50000&types="convenience_store"&key=API_Key](http://APIcall)

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=PID+&key=API_key

I have researched similar questions here on the site and they all say something to the effect of use the type you want in your request URL.

Am I missing something subtle here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have an invalid quotation in your optional request parameter **type**, it also has to be **type** rather than **types** as per [official documentation sample](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#RadarSearchRequests).

I tried to replicate and correct your request URL and it returned the desired response.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=49,-122.2&radius=50000&type=convenience_store&key=API_Key

Please also note that: Radar search is deprecated as of June 30, 2018. After that time, this feature will no longer be available.

Comment: Thanks Xer.  I had actually originally tried type per the documentation.  What I missed was the subtle handling of the type.  I had used the quotes because those were needed when i did keyword lookups with multiple terms.